# Workflow: Trying to pass an object variable to a class method

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I am having a tough time trying to pass a parameter into my method when I go to invoke it.

I new up a variable called setupNewCase, then I populate it with data.  Once I do that, I then try to invoke the method.  It normally works when I don't have a value to pass into it, but it doesn't work here in this case as I am trying to pass something into it.

[image: My screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass parameters to the invoked method you use the `Parameters` property on the `InvokeMethod` activity. Its available on the activity's properties grid and not directly on the designer.

You would use `TargetObject` when invoking a method on an instance object but since your `CommonMethods` class is static you won't ever instantiate it and therefore `TargetObject` should be empty.

Comment: Jota, It works great!!!  Can you tell me what it would look like then if I used the TargetObject?